# SiSTeR. Can't set the "wmode" param for flash

Tags: flash, wmode

I am new in a project. I have to fix a bug with wmode param. The project uses `SiSTeR`.
Trying to configure as `SiSTeR.Config.wmode = "transparent";` makes no effect.
What I am doing wrong?